# iOS simple SQL bug

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, sqlite, uitableview

i have a simple add page which adds items to an SQLite DB and then displays it on a UITableview.

After I add the word 'category' into the list and display it into the tableview, there is a problem with the delete function.

My Primary table is called CATEGORY ,so the delete SQL statement is

```
DELETE FROM ITEMS WHERE CATEGORY = "category"
```

After deleting the category item it also deletes everything else.

How can i prevent the statement from deleting all the items?

Comment: what you want exaclty?

Comment: just to delete the items that are called category and not everything in the table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

put this one,

```
DELETE FROM ITEMS WHERE CATEGORY = 'category'
```

in above code ITEMS is table name and CATEGORY is field name in that table then it'l works fine and give 'category' in single Quotes.